# Creating ads in Facebook for iOS14 app not working

Tags: ios, ios14, capacitor, facebook-ads

I'm trying to set my first FB/IG campaign for an hybrid app made by me with angular/capacitor:

[image]

[This is my app link on app store](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/shootbook/id1581383307)

But the ads form doesn't recognize it and keep saying "choose an app itunes ID".
I tried app ID, app store url, app name, but still same.
By the way, the app was published 4 days ago. Things work if I set iOS < 14.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, you are missing on declare your app ID on App store from this page setting. just finish it and dont forget to save the editing. Hope this help u as does to me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js6lG.png

Comment: Secondly, wait for few mins before it can be visible while creating ad campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
I struggled with this issue for almost a month. The answer is so simple.

First you need to make sure you have your app-ads.txt file set up (ours is literally a single line of text: "facebook.com, [Insert your FB app ID], RESELLER, c3e20eee3f780d68")

Then copy and paste your APPLE app ID into the field labeled "iPhone Store ID" under the iOS section in Settings -> Basic in Meta for Developers.

Confirm your mobile app ownership and hit save at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I would be great to use some formatting so the users understand your answer better

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problems and tried a bunch of stuff (the proposed solution by Cu Huy wasn't it for me since I had the App ID set), like setting the App ID to 0 and then setting it back to the actual App ID. I also switched the app in Meta Developers from Live to Development and back to Live. I have no clue what it was in the end, but after doing these things and reloading the Ad creation page, the error was gone.

Sharing here in case it's useful for anyone.